# How to prevent child node processes from getting killed with the parent node process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, popen

I'm using child_process.spawn/child_process.fork to start a number of child processes from a node.js application. When stopping the parent process with Ctrl-C the child processes are stopped too. Is there an elegant way to keep the child processes running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try catching `SIGINT` in your child:

```
// child.js
process.on("SIGINT", function() { console.log("sigint caught") });

// parent.js
var fork = require("child_process").fork,
    child = fork(__dirname + "/child.js");
```

Run `parent.js` and press `^C`. Your `child.js` should continue running in the background. I don't know what the effects of this will be during the lifetime of `child.js`.

Here is an enlightening, albeit pretty old, discussion of the topic [on the node.js mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/b44d68c60b06c537).

Answer (score 0):

You could call `childprocess.disconnect();` in the parent or `process.disconnect();` in the child.