# Is there another way to start processes than the methods in child_process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

Nodes child_process doesn't work for my use case. What other ways to start processes from a node.js application are available? Google seems to point me to child_process for all queries I've tried.

**Edit** I need to start a number of processes from a node.js application. Those processes need to outlive the 'starting' process. In other words: If the 'starting' process is killed (no matter how) the spawned processes have to keep running unimpeded.

I've tried to intercept SIGINT in processes started with any method in child_process. It kinda works but as soon as the process tries to write to stdout the process crashes.

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what you're trying to do. Why doesn't child_process.spawn work for your case?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311470/how-to-prevent-child-node-processes-from-getting-killed-with-the-parent-node-pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi) as shown in the example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6288426/288425

Just replace `echo $USER` with the process you want to run.