# Wait for a child process to finish before really going down

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

Within a module I am coding, I have a on-shutdown sequence that is meant to kill a good bunch of workers (32+). Problem is, that the parent process simply cuts away and leaves the children on their own. They do exit through their own routines, but there is no way the parent would wait for the children to finish! (Dat bad daddy doe.)

I have been trying everything with Async and other stuff, but none would really stick. I even tried solutions such as  `deasync` - which is based on fibers - but it simply doesn't do anything.

The Processes object looks like so:

```
{
    "Worker group": { 
        config: {/*...*/},
        children: [
            { /* child_process.spawn or cluster.Worker instance */ }
        ]
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is iterate over each group of workers and `SIGTERM` them. But no matter what, the parent exits and leaves the children on its own. Here's my code:

```
// Shutdown handlers
var _shut = false;
this.addShutdownHandler(function(ctx, next){
    if(_shut) return;
    _shut = true;
    for(var id in this.procs) {
        var p = this.procs[id];
        async.forEachOf(p.children, function(c, n, step){
            c.on("exit",step).kill();
        }, next);
    }
}.bind(this));
```

As you can see, I assigned the `step` method as a listener...but that doesn't change anything. How can I make sure that `step` is called when the process is really offline AND without making node hiccup to the end with no further warning? Thanks!

### Edit

I actually managed to find a solution, but it is not entirely what I had looked for. It does the job, but looking at the code, you may understand why I call this "hacky".

```
// Shutdown handlers
var _shut = false;
this.addShutdownHandler(function(ctx, next){
    if(_shut) return;
    _shut = true;
    // Merge all the children together.
    var allChildren = [];
    for(var id in this.procs) {
        var p = this.procs[id];
        p.children.forEach(function(c){
            // Trigger shutdown and add to list.
            c.on("exit", function(){
                c._exited = true;
                c._exitArgs = arguments;
            }).kill(PowerHouse.KILL_SIGNAL);
            allChildren.push(c);
        });
    }

    // Make sure they all are gone.
    var allDone = false;
    async.whilst(
        function() {
            return !allDone;
        },
        function(proceed) {
            var allTrue = [];
            var newChildren = [];
            allChildren.forEach(function(c, i, ref){
                if(!c._exited) {
                    if(c.pid) {
                        try {
                            process.kill(c.pid, 0);
                        } catch (e) {
                            c._exited = true;
                        }
                    } else if(c.process && c.process.pid) {
                        try {
                            process.kill(c.process.pid, 0);
                        } catch (e) {
                            c._exited = true;
                        }
                    } else if(c.isDead) {
                        c._exited = c.isDead();
                    }
                }
                // Overwriting the other array
                if(!c._exited) {
                    newChildren.push(c);
                }
                allTrue.push(c._exited);
            });
            if(allTrue.length > 0) {
                for(var i in allTrue) {
                    if(!allTrue[i]) {
                        allDone = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // There are NO entries. It's safe to say...
                allDone = true;
            }
            allChildren = newChildren;
            // async.nextTick does NOT do this...? I am really surprised.
            // FIXME: ...an answer.
            async.setImmediate(proceed);
        },
        function(err) {
            next(err);
        }
    );
}.bind(this));
```

The further, I should mention that when the parent had exited, I would be returned to my shell and suddenly, messages from other eiting child processes appeared on the same line as the current shell - i.e. as if I had typed that stuff in. I could screenshot it if wanted, but I believe its easily imaginable.

Comment: Any output isn't easily imaginable ... next time include the messages please, even if its just output specific to your program - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather ([How to prevent child node processes from getting killed with the parent node process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311470/how-to-prevent-child-node-processes-from-getting-killed-with-the-parent-node-pro?rq=1)) when the parent dies the children should as well.

Is there something in the children process that would make them ignore SIGTERM? An active DB connection, etc. I would try explicitly catching SIGTERM in your children processes and doing any cleanup necessary in the handler. At the very least this will get the children to exit closer to when the parent does

Comment: I actually am catching `SIGTERM`. The main problem is, that I get a lot of butchered output, actually. Like, once I press Ctrl+C in the app (`SIGINT`), the App does the intended shut-down routines. But mid-process, the main process cuts out and returns me to the shell, whilst suddenly, few output from the exiting child processes gets junked into my shell. and using `ps -ef | grep $appName` shows that they are all gone. I'd partially like to avoid the butchered output and to make sure everything is really offline before the master exits. Any idea on this one?

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix could you edit your original question w/ the output? Answer will depend on whether its a stacktrace or just messages

Comment: @frankprinto Its just messages - there are no errors whatsoever. I did find a solution, actually - but it was a very hard hellride, and did not work with the child_process and cluster events alone.